# Deleting all characters before a token in a stream of multi-line text file

Tags: regex, shell, sed

cat command to a file of my own results in
`ABC:=ABCD

BCD:=BCDE

CDE:=CDEF`

All i want to do is to print it as :
`ABCD

BCDE

CDEF`

The problem is to print the characters after each ":=" foregoing the previous characters.

How can it be achieved using sed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
your_command | sed 's/.*:=//'
```

Comment: Can you refer to me some good ebooks on learning sed ?  I am quite amazed at the power of this command line utility. @devnull

Comment: You can find GNU sed manual in various formats [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/).

Answer (score 0):

Two non-sed ways:

```
...  | awk -F ':=' '{print $NF}'
...  | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "${line##*:=}"; done
```